# how can inject script in node-webkit when visit other url

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, node-webkit

I'm working with node-webkit. I want to do something when node-webkit visits some specific URL, but I don't know how to execute a script when node-webkit visits the other URL.

For example `http://www.google.com`. I can only execute native scripts, but how can I execute a script when I visit another URL like a chrome plugin?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="">
    document.getElementById('id').click();
</script>
```

Script like this can only execute when visit my native script. How can I get it to execute when visiting `http://www.google.com`?

Answer (score 0):

You can always know what the current url is: `window.location`

For your specific example it seems you misunderstood the point of `node-webkit`. Nw does not use `http` protocol; it does use `file` protocol. You do not navigate from one external web page to another external web page as your application is local (desktop).

Be more specific if you want additional help.

Comment: I can visit one external web page with Nw,and chrome plugin can control a page's behavior,i just want to control the page.For example,when i visit google.com with Nw,the page will be shut down,how can i do it.I know I can use Nw as a browser,but how can i inject a script to a external web page?

Comment: You cannot directly. You can however fetch the target page (google i.e.) and parse the content using a parser module.

Answer (score 0):

- It's better not to include or write scripts directly in the HTML. The disadvantage of this technique is that the script (from which you might want to do some background tasks) will reload (or vanish) every time you reload (or navigate to another page).
- 'node-main' in package.json is what you need. Here:
  https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit/wiki/node-main. The scripts stays there even if you visit another page.

Comment: I read the example [node-main](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit/wiki/node-main), but I still don't know how to controll a romote page.This example add `<body onload="process.mainModule.exports.callback0()">`, how can I add this to a romote page when this page isn't mine?

Comment: You should be able to attach an onload listener in your js.
`var gui = require('nw.gui'); var win = gui.Window.get(); win.on('loaded', function() {  console.log('ureka') } );`

Comment: when I try you code, my app will flash back, and I don't know how to solve it, my app just can't be opened.this is my code (https://github.com/Arnoldnuo/node-main)

Comment: wrap everything in main.js into `setTimeout(function(){ #code_here},2000);` . The thing is, window object dsnt even exist when you try to access it the first time. So everything crashes.

Comment: Also, you have written `win.on('minimize',`. Use `win.on('loaded',` in your case.